# Replace path in method of other class during runtime

Tags: python, oop, testing, pytest, path-finding

I have two classes within separate moduls, one class containing actual functionality and the other containing test functionality.

```
ModuleA:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.import_path = None

    def import_data(self):
        self.import_path = sales.__path__["data"]
        self.input = pd.read_excel(
            self.import_path,
            index_col=False,
            engine="openpyxl",
            dtype=object,
        )
        return self.input


ModuleB:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.import_test_path = None

    def test_import_data(self):
        self.import_test_path = self.__path__["data"]

        # Replace actual data paths with test data paths
        ModuleA.import_path = self.import_test_path

        ModuleA.import_data()
```

The problem is that while I have defined a test path in ModuleB, I still cannot overwrite the import_path instantiated in ModuleA even if I call the method, because the path is defined within the method. Is there a way to replace this path with the path from ModuleA, e.g. via Monkeypatching? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Answer found. I just had to place the hardcoded path outside the ModuleA method itself and into its init method. Then, when only calling the method but not instantiating the class, I could pass the right path:

```
ModuleA:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.import_path = sales.__path__["data"]

    def import_data(self):
        self.input = pd.read_excel(
            self.import_path,
            index_col=False,
            engine="openpyxl",
            dtype=object,
        )
        return self.input
```